# Navigating between Ionic tabs and clearing navigation stack

Tags: ionic-framework

My app has three tabs:

- Tab1
- Tab2
- Tab3

On Tab2, the user has progressed an order to completion. At this point, I want to clear the navigation stack for Tab2, and I want to navigate the user to a page that normally sits under Tab3.

Currently, this is what I've got:

```
this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
this.navCtrl.parent.select(TabsPage.Tab3);
this.navCtrl.push(OrderStatusPage);
```

Where TabsPage.Tab3 is the index of Tab3.

The reason I am popping to root is an attempt to clear the pages in the navigation stack so that when the user returns to this tab later, I want them to go back to the root page of that stack.

Then, I followed Ionic's [Tab](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/) documentation which suggested I could change tab by calling `this.navCtrl.parent.select`.

Finally, I'm then trying to push the OrderStatusPage onto the stack.

Here's what happens when I run it:

1. When the application pops to root, it does appear to clear the navigation stack, but in the console I can see that it hits my logon page, which isn't on the Tabs navigation stack, so I don't understand how that happens. I also don't like how it navigates to root. Isn't there some way just to clear the stack without moving the user away from the page?
2. The page then successfully navigates to my Tab3 page, but the command to push the OrderStatusPage onto the stack doesn't seem to register.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Each tab has its own navCtrl, so when you switch to Tab3, you need to push OrderStatusPage into Tab3's navCtrl, but you seem to be using the same `this.navCtrl`.

For Question 2, You don't see `this.navCtrl.push(OrderStatusPage)` result because you switched to tab3, but are still pushing into tab2's `navCtrl`!

For Question 1, you don't mention your complete page structure, but I'm guessing your three tab pages are shown on top of your login page.

You can put each tab page's navCtrl into a service or a global variable like the method that is discussed [here](https://medium.com/@ourarash/handling-android-back-button-in-ionic-33f7cfbba4b9) (*under: Pushing each tab page into the stack*), and then push/pop into them using that service.

Also, as a side note, in case you are taking the user from one step to another step, you can also use [ionic slides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/) instead of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I've come to a solution here was to add the following line of code after selecting the AccountTab:

```
this.navCtrl.parent.select(TabsPage.AccountTab);
setTimeout(() => {this.navCtrl.parent.getSelected().push(OrderStatusPage)}, 100);
```

It's not at all a good solution but hey it works.